# How can i make the program work with different variables without reseting it?

Tags: java, drjava

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TemperaturTo {
  public static void main (String[] args ){

//lager en variabel for Fahrenheit / making a variable for Fahrenheit
 Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.println("Skriv fahrenheit: ");
 float fahrenheit = keyboard.nextInt();


//lager formelen for Celsius ved gitt fahrenheit / implement the formula for Celsius

 double celsius = (fahrenheit - 32) / 1.8;

 //skriver ut et resultat / write out the result

 System.out.println( "Temperatur gitt i fahrenheit:  " + fahrenheit );
 System.out.println( "Temperatur i Celsius: " + celsius );

 if( celsius > 30 && celsius < 50 ){
   System.out.println("Det var for varmt");
 }else if( celsius < 30 && celsius > 25 )  {
   System.out.println("Dette var kanskje for varmt");  
 }else if( celsius == 25 ) {
   System.out.println("Dette var akkurat passelig");
 }else if( celsius < 20 && celsius >= 0 ) {
   System.out.println("Dette var litt for kaldt");
 }else if( celsius < 0 && celsius > -20) {
   System.out.println("Kaldt!");
 }else if( celsius == -273 ) {
   System.out.println("Det absolutte nullpunkt!");
 }else {
   System.out.println("Dette har jeg ingen kommentar om");

  }
 }
}
```

My question is generally how i can make this program work without reseting it? I'm new to this, and i want to loop the scanner function somehow by making the user able to put in several variables for fahrenheit in a stretch, without resetting the entire code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You will want to place most of the code, the code where you get user input and calculate with it an display results into a loop, such as a for loop or while loop. Use a for loop if you know **before** the loop how many times to loop, and use a while loop if you don't, if say you'll exit out of the loop when the user enters some sentinel value.

Answer (score 1):

I propose just wrapping the whole deal in a do-while loop, asking for user input in order to continue iterating, like so:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TemperaturTo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    // lager en variabel for Fahrenheit / making a variable for Fahrenheit
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String answer = null;

    do {
        System.out.println("Skriv fahrenheit: ");
        float fahrenheit = keyboard.nextInt();

        // lager formelen for Celsius ved gitt fahrenheit / implement the
        // formula for Celsius

        double celsius = (fahrenheit - 32) / 1.8;

        // skriver ut et resultat / write out the result

        System.out.println("Temperatur gitt i fahrenheit:  " + fahrenheit);
        System.out.println("Temperatur i Celsius: " + celsius);

        if (celsius > 30 && celsius < 50) {
            System.out.println("Det var for varmt");
        } else if (celsius < 30 && celsius > 25) {
            System.out.println("Dette var kanskje for varmt");
        } else if (celsius == 25) {
            System.out.println("Dette var akkurat passelig");
        } else if (celsius < 20 && celsius >= 0) {
            System.out.println("Dette var litt for kaldt");
        } else if (celsius < 0 && celsius > -20) {
            System.out.println("Kaldt!");
        } else if (celsius == -273) {
            System.out.println("Det absolutte nullpunkt!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Dette har jeg ingen kommentar om");

        }
        System.out.println("Do you want to continue?(Y/N) ");
        answer = keyboard.next();
        while (!answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")
                && !answer.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
            System.out.println("Please answer with Y or N: ");
            answer = keyboard.next();
        }

    } while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));
}
```

}